# Issue with json 1.8.1 in my gemfile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting following error message when running bundle install in my rails app:

```
An error occurred while installing json (1.8.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I then run `gem install json -v '1.8.1'`

and get this error:

```
ERROR:  Error installing json:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/json-1.8.1/ext/json/ext/generator
/Users/home/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160827-41480-bih9j9.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory: /Users/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/json-1.8.1/ext/json/ext/generator
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /Users/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/json-1.8.1/ext/json/ext/generator
make "DESTDIR="
compiling generator.c
In file included from generator.c:1:
./../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:175:47: error: too few arguments provided to function-like macro invocation
    VALUE result = rb_str_new(FBUFFER_PAIR(fb));
                                              ^
/Users/home/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/intern.h:797:9: note: macro 'rb_str_new' defined here
#define rb_str_new(str, len) __extension__ (    \
        ^
In file included from generator.c:1:
./../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:175:11: warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion initializing 'VALUE' (aka 'unsigned long') with an expression of type 'VALUE (const char *, long)' (aka 'unsigned long (const char *, long)') [-Wint-conversion]
    VALUE result = rb_str_new(FBUFFER_PAIR(fb));
          ^        ~~~~~~~~~~
1 warning and 1 error generated.
make: *** [generator.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2
```

Here is my gem file:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.6'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

# allow pry debugging
gem 'pry-byebug'

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

# Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
gem 'spring',        group: :development

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

group :development do
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
end

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

and here is my gemfile.lock:

```
jsoGEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (4.1.6)
      actionpack (= 4.1.6)
      actionview (= 4.1.6)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
    actionpack (4.1.6)
      actionview (= 4.1.6)
      activesupport (= 4.1.6)
      rack (~> 1.5.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.2)
    actionview (4.1.6)
      activesupport (= 4.1.6)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
    activemodel (4.1.6)
      activesupport (= 4.1.6)
      builder (~> 3.1)
    activerecord (4.1.6)
      activemodel (= 4.1.6)
      activesupport (= 4.1.6)
      arel (~> 5.0.0)
    activesupport (4.1.6)
      i18n (~> 0.6, >= 0.6.9)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    arel (5.0.1.20140414130214)
    bcrypt (3.1.7)
    better_errors (2.0.0)
      coderay (>= 1.0.0)
      erubis (>= 2.6.6)
      rack (>= 0.9.0)
    binding_of_caller (0.7.2)
      debug_inspector (>= 0.0.1)
    builder (3.2.2)
    byebug (4.0.5)
      columnize (= 0.9.0)
    coderay (1.1.0)
    coffee-rails (4.0.1)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
    coffee-script (2.3.0)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.8.0)
    columnize (0.9.0)
    debug_inspector (0.0.2)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (2.2.2)
    hike (1.2.3)
    i18n (0.6.11)
    jbuilder (2.2.4)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0, < 5)
      multi_json (~> 1.2)
    jquery-rails (3.1.2)
      railties (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    json (1.8.1)
    mail (2.6.1)
      mime-types (>= 1.16, < 3)
    method_source (0.8.2)
    mime-types (2.4.3)
    minitest (5.4.2)
    multi_json (1.10.1)
    pry (0.10.1)
      coderay (~> 1.1.0)
      method_source (~> 0.8.1)
      slop (~> 3.4)
    pry-byebug (3.1.0)
      byebug (~> 4.0)
      pry (~> 0.10)
    rack (1.5.2)
    rack-test (0.6.2)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (4.1.6)
      actionmailer (= 4.1.6)
      actionpack (= 4.1.6)
      actionview (= 4.1.6)
      activemodel (= 4.1.6)
      activerecord (= 4.1.6)
      activesupport (= 4.1.6)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
      railties (= 4.1.6)
      sprockets-rails (~> 2.0)
    railties (4.1.6)
      actionpack (= 4.1.6)
      activesupport (= 4.1.6)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    rake (10.3.2)
    rdoc (4.1.2)
      json (~> 1.4)
    sass (3.2.19)
    sass-rails (4.0.4)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
      sass (~> 3.2.2)
      sprockets (~> 2.8, < 2.12)
      sprockets-rails (~> 2.0)
    sdoc (0.4.1)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      rdoc (~> 4.0)
    slop (3.6.0)
    spring (1.1.3)
    sprockets (2.11.3)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    sprockets-rails (2.2.0)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
    sqlite3 (1.3.10)
    thor (0.19.1)
    thread_safe (0.3.4)
    tilt (1.4.1)
    turbolinks (2.5.1)
      coffee-rails
    tzinfo (1.2.2)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    uglifier (2.5.3)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      json (>= 1.8.0)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  bcrypt (~> 3.1.7)
  better_errors
  binding_of_caller
  coffee-rails (~> 4.0.0)
  jbuilder (~> 2.0)
  jquery-rails
  pry-byebug
  rails (= 4.1.6)
  sass-rails (~> 4.0.3)
  sdoc (~> 0.4.0)
  spring
  sqlite3
  turbolinks
  uglifier (>= 1.3.0)
```

I have tried commenting out gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'

but I still get the same error.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here besides that I think there might be some dependency issue because I don't even have json 1.8.1 in my gemfile. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [thread](https://github.com/flori/json/issues/229) you might need to upgrade json to 1.8.3 in order to compile it with ruby 2.2 (I'm assuming you're using 2.2)

To update json, try to install it first with:

```
gem install json -v '1.8.3'
```

After that, update the `json` gem in you Gemfile with

```
bundle update json
```

If it won't work, than you probably need to update other gems in your Gemfile which require json < 1.8.3 (I can see `sdoc (0.4.1)` in the Gemfile.lock, for instance). Try to run `bundle update` (without params).

I'd also recommend to update bundler and rubygems.